# Accelerometer on background-yes or no?

Tags: objective-c

I know how to use accelerometer, but we need it to run on background.
I have read here a a lot about that , and i could see different opinions .

Is that possible to put it on background with `core motion ?` or is it just for the first 10 minutes ? do we need a special permission from Apple to leave it running on back ?
how many times is it sample? can i wait ONLY for a certain kind of movements ? 
can you do that with :

```
 startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler
```

If you CAN run it on background, can you give me a sample code or some link ?

Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

I think you can declare your app is one need to know location update and you need pass appstore's review.